# No usable default provider could be found for your system (VM not recognized)

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, vagrant

I am having problems with Vagrant,it does not recognize Oracle VM

When I try:

```
$ vagrant up

No usable default provider could be found for your system.

Vagrant relies on interactions with 3rd party systems, known as
"providers", to provide Vagrant with resources to run development
environments. Examples are VirtualBox, VMware, Hyper-V.
```

CLI shows my VirtualBox version:

```
$ vboxmanage --version

5.2.2r119230
```

And Vagrant version:

```
$ vagrant version

Installed Version: 1.9.1
Latest Version: 2.0.1
```

What is wrong with my settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install a lower virtualbox version than 5.2:

> The VirtualBox provider is compatible with VirtualBox versions 4.0.x, 4.1.x, 4.2.x, 4.3.x, 5.0.x, and 5.1.x. Other versions are unsupported and the provider will display an error message. Please note that beta and pre-release versions of VirtualBox are not supported and may not be well-behaved.

[vagrantup](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/virtualbox/)

Comment: please note that as of today up to version 6.1 is supported

Comment: @RomeoKienzler Thank you, I have noticed that in the vagrant website page.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install latest version https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html via package this work it for me